# Angular 2 getting object object while Class binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, asp.net-core

I, am trying to bind the class in the pagination with the following code.

```
<ul class="pagination hidden-xs pull-right">
   <li *ngFor="let pagItem of _pagination">
       <a style="cursor: pointer;"
           (click)="paginationClick($event)"
           id="{{pagItem.pageNo}}"
           [ngClass]="{'active': pagItem.pageNo === currentPage}">
           {{pagItem.pageNo}}
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In the comparison I am getting object object

Here is the response from the api

[image: Pagination]

The Page and Id is bind successfully. However I am getting the object object on class binding

Here is the image

[image: object object]

Comment: `ng-reflect-attribute-name` will show `[Object object]`(`toString()` form) which is correct.. were you see `active` class is getting applied for `currentPage`???

Comment: What is currentPage?

Comment: You're missing a quotation mark after `[ngClass]=`, by the way.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat my current page is 1

Comment: i would try [ngClass]="{'active': true}"

Comment: @PadraigGalvin I tried with quotation also. It is not working

Comment: That code looks correct. Try logging the values of `pagItem.pageNo` and `currentPage` to the console to check for bugs.

Comment: I think the problem is that - `currentPage` and `pagItem.pageNo` are of different data type. Convert both of them to string or number, then check

Answer (score 4):

This is only because you use an Array at

```
[ngClass]="{'active': pagItem.pageNo === currentPage}"
```

However your code should works.

this has to be used when you have many possible class result like this :

```
[ngClass]="{'active': pagItem.pageNo === currentPage, 'inactive': pagItem.pageNo !== currentPage}"
```

You could also do this to avoid the [Object, Object] rendering,

```
[class.active]="pagItem.pageNo === currentPage"
```

**Be sure that your variable currentPage is set in your component and shared the same type.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this and **ensure** pagItem.pageNo and currentPage are the same type.

```js
    <ul class="pagination hidden-xs pull-right">
    <li *ngFor="let pagItem of _pagination">
        <a style="cursor: pointer;"
            (click)="paginationClick($event)"
            id="{{pagItem.pageNo}}"
            [class.active]="pagItem.pageNo === currentPage">
            {{pagItem.pageNo}}
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and [ngClass] didn't work. Then I changed to different syntax and it solved the problem.
 [class.your-css-class]="yourVariable"

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if you use a ternary expression:

```
[ngClass]="pageItem.pageNo === currentPage ? 'active': ''"
```